# Const-Correctness for Elements of std Containers

Tags: c++, std

The following is bad:

```
vector<const int> vec;
```

The problem is that the template type needs to be assignable.  The following code compiles [EDIT: in Visual Studio 2010], demonstrating a problem with the above:

```
vector<const int> vec;
vec.push_back(6);
vec[0] += 4;
```

With more complicated types, this can be a serious problem.

My first question is whether there is a reason for this behavior.  It seems to me like it might be possible to make const containers that disallow the above and non-const containers that allow it.

Second, is there a way to make containers that function in this way?

Third, what is actually happening here (with a user type)?  I realize it is undefined behavior, but how is the STL even compiling this at all?

Comment: You are using the standard libray in a way that is undefined behaviour. That means that there are *no requirements at all* on what should happen. Some operations might seem to work, others might not. And no consistency to be expected between different implementations.

Comment: This doesn't compile on g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile with c++ standard.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 compiles it.  Hmmmm.

Comment: My guess is that it just wasn't worth the trouble of properly defining how it should work for the standard, since you don't often need such behavior.

Comment: If you know it's UB and just wonder how it's compiling at all, why don't you look at the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `std::vector<T const>` isn't allowed is that the object in a vector may need to be reshuffled when inserting at a different place than the beginning. Now, the member `std::vector<T>::push_back(T const& v)` is conceptually equivalent to (leaving the allocator template parameter out as it is irrelevant for this discussion)

```
template <typename T>
void std::vector<T>::push_back(T const& v) {
    this->insert(this->end(), v);
}
```

which seems to be how it is implemented on some implementations. Now, this operation would requires, in general, that some objects might need to be moved and, thus, the `T` argument needs to be assignable. It seems that the standard library shipping with MSVC++ doesn't delegate the operation but does all the necessary handling, i.e., resizing the array and moving the objects appropriately when running out of space, in `push_back()`. It isn't quite clear what the requirements are on the type `T` to be able to use `push_back()`.

In principle, a container supporting both `T const` and an `insert()` operation in the middle would be possible, though: Nothing requires the internal storage to be `T` rather than `typename std::remove_const<T>::type` while exposing a `T&` in the interface. It is necessary to be a bit careful about the `const`-version ofoperations like `operator[]()` because just using `T const&` as the return type  when `T` is some type `S const` would result in a type `S const const`. In C++ 2003 this would be an error, in C++ 2011 I think the `const` are just collapsed. To be safe you could use `typename std::add_const<T>::type&`.